# How to check if a certain image is on the screen using python

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, computer-vision, pyautogui

So I'm trying to check if there is a notification dot on a fixed position of the screen in a website.

I found another question here which tried to find black and white dots on the screen and I tried it, however it FINDS the dots when it should not, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I tried switching the values around because of the BGR/RGB thing in cv2, but that should not be an issue with numpy? idk, please help.

Here is my code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pyautogui as pya

def test():
    screen = pya.screenshot(region=(550, 90, 30, 50))
    # screen.show()
    img = np.array(screen)
    x, y, z = np.where(img==(173,95,255))
    points = zip(x,y)
    print(points)
    
    if points:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Would be nice if you sent the website you are trying to find the notification dot. And also, when you put code, add the imports, it helps sometimes.

Comment: @JulioLopes the website is Fiverr, it has a pinkish dot for notifications.

Comment: In the notification bell right? right of the name "Fiverr Business" ?

Comment: I am looking for the one Right to the Messages, but they should all look the same. I screenshot only that place, so its a small picture and only thing I want to check is: is there *this* color in this picture at all?

Comment: Found a solution, gonna post it.

Answer (score 4):

Found a good solution.

take a screenshot of the icon which has the small dot you want to find.

Here is my printscreen:
[image: Notification print-screen]

Then, you will put that screenshot in the same folder as your python code and name it notification.png

Then, run this code with the website opened on your screen (with this code, we will find the coordinates of the box that contains the print-screen you just took on the icon + notification dot):

```
import pyautogui
import time

time.sleep(1)
location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('notification.png')
print(location)
```

In my case I received the following output(coordinates):

```
Box(left=1474, top=109, width=52, height=52)
```

Then, We will do the following. Check if this notification image appear at the same place of the screen, so we just do:

```
import pyautogui
import time
r = None
while r is None:
    try:
        location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('notification.png')
        if str(location) == "Box(left=1474, top=109, width=52, height=52)":
            print("found Image!")
        else:
            print("Not found Image!")
        break
    except Exception as e:
        r = None
```

If it finds the image on the screen, It will say found Image, If not, Not found.
It may take a while to render if you are using 2 screens.
So, you can put a timer to break the script in case you think it's taking too long in the not finding case, or you can just restrict the search area.

Comment: *Please leave a like* Kindly refrain from these statements

Comment: Edited, this is not tiktok or IG hehehehe!

Comment: I'm just addicted to Stack Overflow jajjajaja... this is better than gaming.

Comment: Thank you @CesarLopes, I just got around to checking on this, I will try to make it work like this. I do not have an Icon for messages, but I think the code you provided will help me finalize my project. It never occurred to me to check a few times and double-check that it is indeed in the same place.

Comment: Just take a print screen from the icon you wanna look, you don't have to create one. And remember, this will work in your screen, if you change the computer, then you will have to check again for the coordinates.